# Format multiple data to insert in a single column in sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am making an app that uses a sql database that stores the name and price of products purchased by a user in a single column. In my sql database i have a table with only 3 colums which are `id`, `userName` and `products`.

I want to be able to store the `name` and `price` of different products in the `products` column.

so for example, lets say a `user1` chose two items which are `fish` that cost `200` and `meat` that cost `500`. i want it to insert like this

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT ("[P1: fish,200],[p2: meat, 500]")...
```

and the output should look like this

```
Name: "user1"

Products:

1. Product name: "fish"
   Product price: "200"

2. Product name: "meat"
   Product price: "500"
```

I'm very new to sql and sorry if this question has been asked before. I tried searching but the answers didn't answer my question and some say you cant store multiple data in a column but I'm certain it can store it if it inserts everything in the database as a text. I just dont know how to format the statement so i can easily remove the information and arrange them like shown in the output

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but why not `INSERT INTO table1 (name,price) VALUES ('fish', '200'),('meat', '500')`

Comment: It is not a good design to try to make a database within a string stored in a single column in a table in a database. To put it differently, store the different pieces of information in appropriatly declared dedicated columns.

Comment: Parsing the four infos from the single string, in pure SQLite, is possible, but really horrible. Please change to a many-to-one relation design. See answer by xtratic.

Comment: ok I will look into it. Thanks @Yunnosch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to put a list of data into a single column..

Instead each row of the `PRODUCTS` table should be an element of your list.

I would say your database should look something like this:

```
PRODUCTS
  PURCHASE_ID  | PRODUCT_NAME | PRODUCT_PRICE
  -------------+--------------+--------------
  1            | oatmeal      | 2.49
  1            | eggs         | 0.79
  1            | cereal       | 2.99
  2            | milk         | 1.25
  2            | chicken      | 7.49
  2            | cereal       | 2.99
  3            | energy drink | 4.25


PURCHASES 
  ID | USER_NAME
  ---+----------
  1  | billy bob 
  2  | john smith
  3  | mark brown
```

In this case `PRODUCTS->PURCHASE_ID` is a foreign key that pairs with `PURCHASES->ID`

To get the products that billy bob bought:

```
SELECT (PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_PRICE) FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PRUCHASE_ID == 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I will look into making a separate element for products and assign a foreign key. Any help to where I can find codes to help me do that will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I used this method Instead. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

@Yunnosch's comment and @xtratic's answer are valid. But if you can't change the database ...

Format your string using some symbol, such as a comma, which can make the parsing easier. Then, when you read the sting, its simple to separate it into the substrings you need using [`split(",")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)). You can iterate over the returned `String[]` to find the sub-fields.

Assuming you have a result set (rs) with the query results,

```
String myInput = product + "," + price.toString();
// Save to database

...

// Query data
String[] myResults = rs.getString(resultColumnIndex).split(",");
String product = myResults[0];
String price = myResults[1];

...
// Format your output ...
```

Comment: Yeah thats the problem. I can't change the database. The database only allows me to enter the entire product detail in only one column

Comment: After closely looking at my data structure this will not work for me because it makes it more stressful using the details in the table individually. Just as the previous answer supports, its best to use a separate table to hold those details individual and store them under a foreign key as this greatly increases the ease of use and versatility of the data. But thanks for the help. Your reply was for what I was asking for and not what I actually should do